# Whether an npm package size is small or large

Tags: npm-package

My project has a package named "vue-ctk-date-time-picker", its unpacked size is 6.17Mb.
I don't know whether the package size is small or large. So please tell me how should I be aware of a package size used in a project.

And I tend to write a new component if the package is a large package since I only need a simple datepicker and also be able to style it easily.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you rewrite a package if it's 'large' but don't have a definition of large? The size of an npm package may not be representative of the actual code you're using in your build.

Comment: thank you, @Evert. Your comment is very concise and informative. I want to mark it as answer for my concern but unfortunately, I can't.